# :extend face text property in prog mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

Using tip of trunk emacs.

I am doing this to print a horizontal line:

`(insert (propertize "\n" 'face '(:inherit shadow :extend t :underline t)))`

It works in fundamental mode, but not in prog mode.

How to make it work in prog mode?

Comment: It works after disabling font-lock-mode in prog-mode. But how to have it and keep font-lock-mode enabled?

Comment: This seems a lot like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you want to insert a horizontal line in code?